# crash removing keyValue observer (using Apple SquareCam example code)

Tags: ios, ios5, key-value-observing

I am using the viewController class from Apple's SquareCam demo. I haven't changed the code except to create a UIView which in the example was being set through the storyboard/IB. Also specify in build settings to exclude from ARC.

The code uses KVO to do some animation I'm getting a crash on the `removeObserver` line below.

I can easily work around this and not use KVO but I'd like to understand the issue - and KVO better. Sometimes KVO in code examples is hard to follow. For example: in the snippets below, the `keyPaths` for the `addObserver/removeObserver`calls are different (in Apple's code). Shouldn't they be the same?

Anyway... if someone has x-ray vision

```
- (void)teardownAVCapture
{
[videoDataOutput release];
if (videoDataOutputQueue)
    dispatch_release(videoDataOutputQueue);

    // CRASH HERE
[stillImageOutput removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"isCapturingStillImage"];

[stillImageOutput release];
[previewLayer removeFromSuperlayer];
[previewLayer release];
}
```

// the observer is set up here:

```
    stillImageOutput = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput new];
[stillImageOutput addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"capturingStillImage" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:AVCaptureStillImageIsCapturingStillImageContext];
```

Answer (score 6):

I also meet this problem when trying to retake a picture, my temporary solution is rem that code

```
[stillImageOutput removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"isCapturingStillImage"];
```

and try to call

```
[session stopRunning]
```

Comment: Instead of using `>` for your code, use 4 spaces instead. Your code will be highlighted.

Answer (score 4):

I treat it as no more than a typo in SquareCam and use:

```
[stillImageOutput removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"capturingStillImage"];
```

Answer (score 1):

if i'm not wrong

`isCapturingStillImage` and `capturingStillImage` values should match.

if the app could not find the matching observer , than it crashes..

hope this helps..

Comment: yes, unless they are observing multiple items....  Then he would need to add and remove both.

Comment: I just double checked the source from Apple's site and the names don't match - hence my confusion. Could this be their bug - or maybe they are doing something more that I missed/haven't posted here.   http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SquareCam/Listings/SquareCam_SqareCamViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011190-SquareCam_SqareCamViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_4

Comment: I have the same crash issue. Do you have any update ? Do we need to keep different string for isCapturingStillImage and capturingStillImage ?